# How can a HashSet record a null entry without a NullPointerException when computing the hash code

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, set

I know all those weird *philosophical reasons* why *null* instances are allowed in every collection

But unlike in lists,position of sets' (even maps, too) elements depend upon the **hashcode** of element being added thereby on the element itself (barring exceptions like `LinkedHashSet` where insertion order is preserved)

So while computing hashcode of element being added to collection and if that element is presumed to be **null** shouldn't it throw **NPE** ?

> `null.hashCode()`

Does it have some type of *null-checking*

First i thought
**System.out.println(setReference)** too should generate **NPE** if there is a *null*, but after quite a bit research i found that actual method that is called is static **valueOf(Object obj)** rather than **toString()** method
which is null safe from what is stated in java docs,
i have finally been to clear my head about it ...

but this still haunts me, i know i am being little obsessive about tiny details but i have to 'cause currently i am preparing for OCAJP 8 so i risked  downrating to get credible explanation since i didn't find anything in java docs pertaining to this...

so what operations in sets are null-safe, a comprehensive answer is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if javadoc isn't enough, read source code. And what is wrong with ... just giving it a try? Typically you learn a lot more from making your own experiences; instead of asking other people to give ready-to-digest answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`null` are handled explicitly. If you look at `HashSet`'s implementation, it's basically a `HashMap` where all the keys point to the same (dummy) value. If you drill down to the way `HashMap` calculates the hash code for a key, you'd find this method (code taken from OpenJDK 1.8.0_92-b14, although I sincerely doubt it will differ in any other JDK):

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

So, to make a long story short, `HashSet`s and `HashMap`s explicitly handle `null`s and treat their hash as 0.

Comment: thanks for the elegant answer, that is what i needed so hash code of null is stored as 0. :)